# Add *, but sibling is being ignored

Tags: git, gitignore

I made a bunch of updates inside a directory and would like to add them, but they sit beside a directory which I have in my .gitignore. Shouldn't `git add` just **ignore** that instead of complaining?

How can I add everything and just skip the thing being ignored?

```
$ git add assets/*
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
assets/avatars
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-add), the `--ignore-errors` flag would just make the command work as you'd like.

> If some files could not be added because of errors indexing them, do not abort the operation, but continue adding the
>   others. The command shall still exit with non-zero status. The
>   configuration variable add.ignoreErrors can be set to true to make
>   this the default behaviour.

**Update:**

This doesn't work in this case, I guess because the `assets/*` parameter is expanded by the shell so that the actual parameters received by `git add` are the expanded list of files and directories and so the failure is explicit.

I've tried this command with good results:

```
$ git add assets
```

It works even without the option `--ignore-errors` because it doesn't try to add the ignored directory below `assets`.

Comment: Get same error with "git add --ignore-errors assets/*"

Comment: Yes, it happened to me as well, and I'm using git 1.8.1. But I check it doesn't fail, even if not using the `--ignore-errors` option if using just the name of the directory, `assets` in your case. I update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the wildcard `*`, it will be expanded by your shell on Unix systems.  Thus, running `git add assets/*` is the equivalent of explicitly adding files beneath `assets/avatars`.

For example, if I have two files:

```
assets/file1.txt
assets/avatars/file2.txt
```

Then running `git add assets/*` is expanded to:

```
git add assets/file1.txt assets/avatars/file2.txt
```

So git complains that you are instructing it to add an ignored file.  If you want to avoid this message, you can quote the `*` to allow git to do the globbing.  This will instruct git to expand your paths, paying attention to the `.gitignore` file.  For example:

```
git add assets/\*
```

Produces no warnings and stages only the appropriate files, in this example, `assets/file1.txt`.